# Find wrong prediction label and its file path in Keras CNN

Tags: python, keras

I created a model with my image dataset with `image_dataset_from_directory`

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  'drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/sample_database',
...
)
```

It's ok, **But** How can I access my wrong labels and their file path in prediction. I just want to check the names of the images that were predicted wrong.